# Sending Email using C# without hardcoding username and password and using domain credentials

Tags: c#, email

Is there a way to send emails in C# which uses Windows Domain USernaem and Password and I don't have to  explicitly mention the username and password

Comment: What do you mean by "uses?"  Do you mean your email server requires a username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SmtpClient class for sending emails using Windows authentication. FOr this just init `UseDefaultCredentials` property to true;

```
string to = "jane@contoso.com";
string from = "ben@contoso.com";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
message.Body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
// Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client  
// to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

try 
{
  client.Send(message);
}  
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

This will require your application to run as administrator and have permission to send emails on behalf of the specified sender.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but i get an error, how can i force the run as admin here ?

Comment: Thanks, I made some typos.. It works.